# Spring\AspectJ error

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Good night!There is a type mismatch error if I remove the aspect of the error disappears , why is this happening? Aspect also written correctly. if this class is not used for injection, and create as a bob(Sender sender = (Sender) context.getBean("sendService");), everything works fine,  I have not seen this in the documentation

Aspect

```
package com.work.Spring.Aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AspectLogger 
{
//private Logger Log = Logger.getLogger("stdout");

@Pointcut("execution(* com.work.Interfaces.sendingMechanizm.send(String, String))" +
        " && args(messageText, destination)")
public void send(String messageText, String destination) {}

@Before("send(messageText, destination)")
public void test(String messageText, String destination)
{
    System.out.println("Test");
}
}
```

interface

```
package com.work.Interfaces;

public interface sendingMechanizm 
{
public void send(String messageText, String destination);
}
```

implementation  interface

```
package com.work.Spring.mainClass.sendingMechanizms;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.skype.ContactList;
import com.skype.Friend;
import com.skype.Skype;
import com.skype.SkypeException;
import com.work.Interfaces.sendingMechanizm;
import com.work.Spring.Exception.SkypeNotRunning;
import com.work.Spring.Exception.notFoundUserException;

@Component("sendSkype")
public class sendSkype implements sendingMechanizm 
{
private ContactList contactList = null;

private Date lastUpdate = null;

public void send(String messageText, String destination) 
{
    try 
    {
        if (Skype.isRunning())
        {
            initContactList();
            String userId = searchFriend(destination);
            if(userId.equals(""))
                throw new notFoundUserException();
            else
                sendMessage(messageText, userId);
        }
        else
            throw new SkypeNotRunning();
    } 
    catch (SkypeException | notFoundUserException | SkypeNotRunning e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String searchFriend(String destination) throws SkypeException
{
    String userId = "";
    for (Friend friend : contactList.getAllFriends())
    {
        if (friend.getFullName().equals(destination))
        {
            userId = friend.getId();
            break;
        }
    }
    return userId;
}

private void sendMessage(String message, String userId) throws SkypeException
{
    Friend friend = contactList.getFriend(userId);
    friend.send(message);
}

private void initContactList() throws SkypeException
{
    if (contactList == null)
    {   
        contactList = Skype.getContactList();
        lastUpdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    else
    {
        checkDateUpdate();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void checkDateUpdate() throws SkypeException
{
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    if (currentDate.getDay() > lastUpdate.getDay() || 
            currentDate.getMonth() > lastUpdate.getMonth() ||
            currentDate.getYear() > lastUpdate.getYear())
        contactList = Skype.getContactList();


}
}
```

Inject bean class

```
package com.work.Spring.mainClass;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

 import com.work.Interfaces.Sender;
 import com.work.Model.Reminder;
 import com.work.Spring.mainClass.sendingMechanizms.sendMail;
 import com.work.Spring.mainClass.sendingMechanizms.sendSkype;
 import com.work.Spring.mainClass.sendingMechanizms.sendVk;

 @Service("sendService")
 public class sendService implements Sender<Reminder> 
 {
private ReminderService reminderService;

private sendMail sendMail;

private sendVk sendVk;

private sendSkype sendSkype;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void startSending() 
{
    for (Reminder reminder : reminderService.getAll())
    {
        String message = reminder.getMessage();
        String destination = reminder.getData();
        switch (reminder.getType()) 
        {
            case "Mail":
            {
                sendMail.send(message, destination);
                break;
            }

            case "Vk":
            {
                sendVk.send(message, destination);
                break;
            }

            case "Skype":
            {
                sendSkype.send(message, destination);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public ReminderService getReminderService() {
    return reminderService;
}

@Autowired
public void setReminderService(ReminderService reminderService) {
    this.reminderService = reminderService;
}

public sendMail getSendMail() {
    return sendMail;
}

@Autowired
public void setSendMail(sendMail sendMail) {
    this.sendMail = sendMail;
}

public sendVk getSendVk() {
    return sendVk;
}

@Autowired
public void setSendVk(sendVk sendVk) {
    this.sendVk = sendVk;
}

public sendSkype getSendSkype() {
    return sendSkype;
}

@Autowired
public void setSendSkype(sendSkype sendSkype) {
    this.sendSkype = sendSkype;
}
 }
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sendService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.work.Spring.mainClass.sendService.setSendMail(com.work.Spring.mainClass.sendingMechanizms.sendMail); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.work.Spring.App.main(App.java:22)
```

Comment: Let's see your `setSendMail` class and your context configuration. Also, java naming conventions state that you should be using an upper case letter to start your class names. Package names should all start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using JDK proxies. The proxy wrapping your bean of type `sendMail` will actually only be implementing its interfaces, I'm assuming `sendingMechanizm`.

When trying to invoke your

```
public void setSendMail(sendMail sendMail) {
```

method through reflection, Spring will pass it your proxy. An object of type `sendingMechanizm` (the proxy) is not a valid argument for a parameter of type `sendMail`.

Change your configuration to use CGLIB proxies using `proxy-target-class="true"` or the corresponding Java configuration. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).